# CSS: Can I fit a container to a long/overflowing image?

Tags: html, css, sass

One of my first css intensive projects, having trouble getting everything lined up how I'd want it to.

[How it is and what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flIfo.png)

The second section is ignoring the overblown 600% image and going right after the previous container (obviously).
I tried setting the .container-stars height to 600%, but that does literally nothing.
Tried using px or vh units, but it messes with the SVG paths, where they ignore the absolute top: 0; and move to the middle (I imagine it's because of the height: 100% somehow, but I can't set it to specific units because then it wouldn't be responsive anymore)

[When I set the .container-stars to height: 600vh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8cFa.png)

```css
.container-stars {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 20%;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, $background 5%, white 40%, transparent 100%, $background 90%);
  .path_left {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    fill: $background;
  }
  .path_right {
    position: absolute;
    width: 45%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
    fill: $background;
  }
  .img_stars {
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url('/img/stars-1654074_1920.jpg');
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 600%;
    repeat: repeat-y;
    z-index: -1;
  }
}

#content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 0%;
  h2 {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: $primary-font;
    font-size: calc(2vw + 0.5rem);
    top: 0;
    background: green;
    display: block;
    transform: translate(0, 50%);
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container-stars">
  <svg class="path_left" width="450" height="600" viewBox="0 0 450 600">
      <path d="M 0 600 C 260 327 202 133 450 0 L 0 0"></path>
    </svg>
  <svg class="path_right" width="450" height="600" viewBox="0 0 450 600">
      <path d="M 0 600 C 260 327 202 133 450 0 L 0 0"></path>
    </svg>
  <div class="img_stars"></div>
</section>

<section id="content">
  <h2>...matter, energy, time and space came into being</h2>
</section>
```

Would also appreciate any tips if someone has a better way to achieve this.
Troubleshooting whilst trying to maintain responsiveness can really be a pain.

Comment: `600vh` is invalid. Also you need to use a container to contain the image and the text. Then give the container a `position: relative`  and the text a `position: absolute; bottom: 0;` PS: Unelss you use somethign like SASS, you cant nest css selectors. For standard css its invalid.

Comment: @tacoshy is right. That's exactly how I would do it as well. The relative position makes sure that the child div stays inside the container with an absolute positioning, and bottom 0 would make it stick to the bottom of that container. Alternatively use margin left and right auto to center your absolute positioned div if you need to, or fiddle with whatever values you need.

Comment: @tacoshy `600vh` is not invalid - it is perfectly valid. The OP is also using SASS/SCSS - look at the tags on the question.

Comment: which have been added later on. thats why the question.

Comment: Yes, moving out the containers makes things a bit easier, thank you @tacoshy ! Guess it's just a way of thinking one has to get used to. But now am having trouble with the [svg paths](https://i.imgur.com/kGP7kY5.png), any idea how to make them stick to the top of their viewBoxes? Somehow it's also going outside it's [viewBox size](https://i.imgur.com/n6fZKzT.png). Not sure why they worked so well before, when everything was squished together...